# How to remove sub child after filtering from Realtime firebase with indexOn

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to remove expired users in cat01.So i want to filter date from nodes and remove that user node only.
Following is my firebase structure.

[image: firebase Structre]

I tried this below code .It shows successfully .but the node is not deleted.

```
deleteData: function (req, callback, res) {
     {
     let userId = req.User;
    
     const db = firebase.database()
  
     let usersRef = db.ref("Foreign/").child(userId).child("Category").child("Cat01")
     usersRef 
       .equalTo(uid)
       .once("value")
       .then(function (snapshot) {
         snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
         usersRef.child(childSnapshot.key).remove();
         });
       });
```

Method 2
i tried this way too .but it remove whole user from UserID. But i just want to remove uid="u001" when date is expired.it is successful until cat01.i think error cause because of index. May i know any method to access index there .

```
 deleteData: function (req, callback, res) {
        {
        let userId = req.User;
       
        const db = firebase.database()
     
    
        let usersRef = db.ref("Foreign/").child(userId).child("Category").child("Cat01")
        usersRef.remove()
              .then(function() {
                console.log("succeeded!")
              })
              .catch(function(error) {
                console.log("failed: ",error)
              });
```

Comment: Have you tried to check if something went wrong when you performed the remove operation?

Comment: I tried. I couldn't find any

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an `orderBy...` call in your query here:

```
usersRef 
   .equalTo(uid)
   .once("value")
   ...
```

To order/filter on the `uid` property, use:

```
usersRef 
   .orderByChild("uid") // 
   .equalTo(uid)
   .once("value")
   ...
```

---

To allow the above query to work efficiently, you'll need to add an index to your security rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ...
    "Foreign": {
      "$userId": {
        "Category": {
          "$categoryId": {
            ".indexOn": "uid"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i added it . i think i can not access it because of index. may i know any method how to access index like ".indexOn": "transaction_id" .or else
may i know in my second ,method  how to access index and then uid. it successful until cat01.

Comment: "i think i can not access it because of index" I'm not sure what you mean there. Do you mean you get an error message about a missing index? Because this indeed does indeed that you add an index as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data. I added what I think should be your index definition to my answer.

Comment: Hey @KUL. Any further updates here?

Answer (score 0):

Accourding to the structure in your Realtime you still need to go a farther child which is 'user'.
**But** if you want to get on multiple children for Cat01 that also have multiple children you can't do that, because Realtime pagination works only with one level of multiple children

So you have to do this:

```
let usersRef = db.ref("Foreign/").child(userId).child("Category").child("Cat01").child('user')
```

Or if you have multiple children like 'user', you have to do each one in a separate query.

Comment: Thank you . i add user also. But still the same error happening. May i know is there any error with code .